# What is the recommended notation for bowed marimba?

Tags: notation, strings, percussion

I've been writing a piece for winds and marimba, and I was looking to see if there was a proper way to notate this technique. I haven't seen an answer on music forums, but have heard many pieces use this. The bars are to be bowed across the corner with a fiberglass bass bow, and my current method is to use string up+down bowings. How, if there is a better way, should this be written?

Comment: interesting question. You are probably on the right track using standard upbow and downbow markings.  I would also add the word "Arco" at the top of the passage, indicating that it is played bowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine and standard just to write arco or some equivalent in another language (just writing "bowed" is also fine).  See [this page](https://www.vsl.co.at/en/Marimba/Playing_Techniques#!Marimba-Double_bass_bow) for more stuff on marimba techniques.

I don't know that up/down markings would be necessary--would it make any difference to the sound produced?  If not, don't include them; that would be unnecessary and only confuse the player, while making the music more cluttered.

Comment: CHEESE is correct.  Elaine Gould recommends verbal written instructions and to not use up-bow down-bow markings, as they make no difference.  Kurt Stone concurs also.  My recommendation you purchase books like this still stands: you will refer to them time and time again as you develop as a composer.

Answer (score 0):

It's time for you to purchase a good book on notation.  You will not regret it.  The Kurt Stone *Music Notation in the 20th Century* is a classic, although I also like the Elaine Gould *Behind Bars: the Definitive Guide to Music Notation* very much.

Comment: Do either of these sources discuss bowed marimba notation? Can you share with us what they say?